# How to replace a specific char from a string with an accessor method

Tags: c++

I know how to replace a character in a string, but how would you do it with that specific method. For example, you have an array of an object named `object *objArr[]`, and you have a method defined in your class `getName`. With a string, you would do `string name` and have it `name.replace(" ", '_')`(just an example). With an object, you would access it `objArr[]->getName()`.

I tried doing `objArr[]->getName().replace()` but it did not work.

```
       //changes all the space to a _ for the names.
            for (int y = 0; y < name.length(); y++)
            {
                if (name.substr(y, 1) == " ")
                {
                    name[y] = '_';
                }
            }
```

Bad english sorry!

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: what is the return type of getName() ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is the point of having a getter function if it doesn't actually get/return anything?

As far as I can tell, you have a class object which has an attribute name which you want to replace a char from. You have a few options:

- You can create a method for the object which takes as parameters the char you want to replace for the object and what you want to replace it with. So you would call

  ```
      object1->replaceChar(char from, char to)
  ```
- You get the name of the object string and then just replace it, and set it as the attribute of the object.

  ```
      string name = object1->getName();
      name.replace(foo, bar);
      object1->setName(name);
  ```

First option seems like a better option to me if you plan on using this more than once.

Comment: it was a mistake on my part, the get funtion returns the name & having name = to the object would not work it crashes

Comment: @theRat What do you mean with "having name = to the object would not work it crashes"?  Of course you cant assign an object to a string, but if your getName() function returns a string you can assign that to name.